# QtCreat J-Link JLinkGDBServer crashed

Tags: gdb, qt-creator

I have setup the Qtcreator kits for NRF52832 as
mainly in this post:
search:'edgetx/wiki/Building-and-debugging-with-Qt-Creator'

All builds and deploy fine but when I start the debugger I get this:

```
7:25:56: Unable to create a debugging engine.
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.88a Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.88a (DLL compiled Nov 18 2020 16:08:10)

Command line: -port 2331 -select usb -if SWD -speed 1000 -device NRF52832_XXAA
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 NRF52832_XXAA
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
17:25:57: The program has unexpectedly finished.
17:25:57: The process was ended forcefully.
17:25:57: /opt/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer crashed.
</code>

Though from a shell command

<code>
$ /opt/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer -port 2331 -select usb -if SWD -speed 1000 -device NRF52832_XXAA
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.88a Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.88a (DLL compiled Nov 18 2020 16:08:10)

Command line: -port 2331 -select usb -if SWD -speed 1000 -device NRF52832_XXAA
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 NRF52832_XXAA
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link OB-SAM3U128-V2-NordicSemi compiled Feb  2 2021 16:47:20
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 682207044
Feature(s): RDI, FlashBP, FlashDL, JFlash, GDB
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection..
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.

- Qt->tools->options->kits->debugger->Manual [arm-none-eabi-gdb-py] from the toolchain I use
- `apt install --reinstall libpython2.7`